# How to edit a selected item from a list in flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout

I have been trying to add an edit function to my to do list in which a user can select the item the user wants to edit, then that should pop a dialog where there is a textfield to enter the new value of the selected item and a Button that saves the changes. Currently I have a function that calls the array where the tasks are stored then it is supposed to triger the selected item using index so that at the end that selected value could be given a new value when onPressed, see this edit functionality as instagrams one except it edits text.

The problem comes when calling that function into the dialog's edit button because I am doing it like this `onPressed: () => _editToDoItem(_controller.text, index)` and since I have to pass 2 parameters there, the error I am getting is `Undefined name 'index'`. How can this problem be solved to make this edit function work?. By the way, I haven't get to try the edit function because of this error so please correct me if the function or any part of the code is incorrect.

everything to do with the edit function below.

```
  List<ToDoElement> _toDoItems = [];
  TextEditingController _controller = TextEditingController();

  // this function adds a task to the list
  void _addToDoItem(String task) {
    if(task.isNotEmpty) {
      setState(() {  
        _toDoItems.add(ToDoElement(task, DateTime.now()));
      });
    }
  }

  // this is the function that is supposed to edit the selected index from the _toDoItems array
  void _editToDoItem(String newText, int index) {
    setState(() {
      _toDoItems[index].task = newText;
    });
  }

  _editDialog(BuildContext context) {
    return showDialog(context: context, builder: (context) {
      return Dialog(
        child: Container(
          height: 180,
          width: 100,
          child: Column(
            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
            children: [
                Container(
                  height: 60, 
                  child: TextField(
                    controller: _controller,
                    autofocus: true,
                    style: TextStyle(fontSize: 18,),
                  )
                ), 
                Container(
                  height: 65,
                  width: double.infinity,
                  margin: EdgeInsets.only(top: 5,),
                  child: RaisedButton(
                    textColor: Colors.white,
                    color: Colors.red,
                    child: Text('EDIT'),
                    onPressed: () {
                      _editToDoItem(_controller.text, index); // error on index, Undefined name 'index'
                      FocusScope.of(context).requestFocus(FocusNode());
                    },
                  ),
                ),                                          
            ],
          ),
        ),
      );
    });
  }
```

full main.dart file

```
class ToDoElement {
  String task;
  final DateTime timeOfCreation;

  ToDoElement(this.task, this.timeOfCreation);
}

void main() => runApp(MaterialApp(home: MyApp()));

class MyApp extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  createState() => MyAppState();
}



class MyAppState extends State<MyApp> {
  List<ToDoElement> _toDoItems = [];
  TextEditingController _controller = TextEditingController();

  void _addToDoItem(String task) {
    if(task.isNotEmpty) {
      setState(() {  
        _toDoItems.add(ToDoElement(task, DateTime.now()));
      });
    }
  }

  void _editToDoItem(String newText, int index) {
    setState(() {
      _toDoItems[index].task = newText;
    });
  }

  void _removeTodoItem(int index) {
    setState(() => _toDoItems.removeAt(index));
  }

  _editDialog(BuildContext context) {
    return showDialog(context: context, builder: (context) {
      return Dialog(
        backgroundColor: Colors.transparent,
        child: Container(
          decoration: BoxDecoration(
            color: Colors.white,
            borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(20.0)),
          ),
          padding: EdgeInsets.all(20),
          height: 180,
          width: 100,
          child: Column(
            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
            children: [
                Container(
                  height: 60, 
                  child: TextField(
                    controller: _controller,
                    autofocus: true,
                    /*onSubmitted: (val) {
                      _addToDoItem(val);
                      _controller.clear();
                    },*/
                    style: TextStyle(fontSize: 18,),
                    decoration: InputDecoration(
                      hintText: 'Add a task here...',
                      enabledBorder: OutlineInputBorder(
                        borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(12.0)),
                        borderSide: BorderSide(color: Colors.red, width: 2),
                      ),
                      focusedBorder: OutlineInputBorder(
                        borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(12.0)),
                        borderSide: BorderSide(color: Colors.red, width: 2),
                      ),
                      
                    ),
                  )
                ),

              
                   
                Container(
                  height: 65,
                  width: double.infinity,
                  margin: EdgeInsets.only(top: 5,),
                  child: RaisedButton(
                    textColor: Colors.white,
                    color: Colors.red,
                    child: Text('EDIT', style: TextStyle(fontSize: 18)),
                    
                    shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
                      borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(12)),
                    ),
                    onPressed: () {
                      _editToDoItem(_controller.text, index);
                      FocusScope.of(context).requestFocus(FocusNode());
                    },
                  ),
                ),                                          
            ],
          ),
        ),
      );
    });
  }

  Widget _buildToDoItem(String toDoText, int index) {
    return SizedBox(
      child: Container(
        height: 58,
        margin: EdgeInsets.only(left: 22.0, right: 22.0, bottom: 12,),
        decoration: BoxDecoration(
          border: Border.all(width: 1.5, color: Colors.red),
          borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(18)),
        ),
        child: Row(
          crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
          children:[
            Expanded(
              child: ListTile(
                title: Text(
                  toDoText,
                  style: TextStyle(fontSize: 18),
                ),
                onTap: () => null,
              ),
            ),
            FlatButton(
              child: Text('Edit', style: TextStyle(color: Colors.red, fontSize: 16.5),),
              onPressed: () => _editDialog(context),
            ),
            FlatButton(
              child: Text('Delete', style: TextStyle(color: Colors.red, fontSize: 16.5),),
              onPressed: () => _removeTodoItem(index),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }

  int compareElement(ToDoElement a, ToDoElement b) =>
      a.timeOfCreation.isAfter(b.timeOfCreation) ? -1 : 1;

  Widget _buildToDoList() {
    _toDoItems.sort(compareElement);
    return Expanded(
      child: ListView.builder(
        itemCount: _toDoItems.length,
        itemBuilder: (context, index) {
          if (index < _toDoItems.length) {
            return _buildToDoItem(_toDoItems[index].task, index);
          }
        },
      ),
    );
  }
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
        appBar: PreferredSize(
          preferredSize: Size.fromHeight(50),
          child: AppBar(
            centerTitle: true,
            backgroundColor: Colors.red,
            title: Text('To Do List', style: TextStyle(fontSize: 24, fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,),),
          )
        ),
        backgroundColor: Colors.white,
        body: GestureDetector(
          onTap: () {
            FocusScope.of(context).requestFocus(FocusNode());
          },
          child: Column(
            crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
            children: [
              Container(
                height: 60,
                margin: EdgeInsets.all(22),
                child: Row(
                  crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
                  children: [
                    Expanded(
                      flex: 10,
                      child: Container(
                        height: double.infinity,
                        child: TextField(
                          controller: _controller,
                          autofocus: true,
                          onSubmitted: (val) {
                            _addToDoItem(val);
                            _controller.clear();
                          },
                          style: TextStyle(fontSize: 18,),
                          
                          decoration: InputDecoration(
                            hintText: 'Add a task here...',
                            enabledBorder: OutlineInputBorder(
                              borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(12.0)),
                              borderSide: BorderSide(color: Colors.red, width: 2),
                            ),
                            focusedBorder: OutlineInputBorder(
                              borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(12.0)),
                              borderSide: BorderSide(color: Colors.red, width: 2),
                            ),
                            
                          ),
                        ),
                      ),
                      
                    ),
                    Expanded(
                      flex: 4,    
                      child: Container(
                        height: double.infinity,
                        margin: EdgeInsets.only(left: 12),
                        child: RaisedButton(
                          textColor: Colors.white,
                          color: Colors.red,
                          child: Text('ADD', style: TextStyle(fontSize: 18)),
                          
                          shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
                            borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(12)),
                          ),
                          onPressed: () {
                            _addToDoItem(_controller.text);
                            _controller.clear();
                            FocusScope.of(context).requestFocus(FocusNode());
                          },
                        ),
                      ),                                          
                    ),
                  ],
                ),
              ), 
              _buildToDoList()
            ]
          ), 
                 
        ),
    );
  }
}
```

If you have any questions please let me know in the comments;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can copy paste run full code below 
You can provide `index` to `_editDialog` then `_editToDoItem` can get `index`
code snippet

```
_editDialog(BuildContext context, int index)
...
FlatButton(
      child: Text(
        'Edit',
        style: TextStyle(color: Colors.red, fontSize: 16.5),
      ),
      onPressed: () => _editDialog(context, index),
    ),
```

working demo

[image]

full code

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class ToDoElement {
  String task;
  final DateTime timeOfCreation;

  ToDoElement(this.task, this.timeOfCreation);
}

void main() => runApp(MaterialApp(home: MyApp()));

class MyApp extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  createState() => MyAppState();
}

class MyAppState extends State<MyApp> {
  List<ToDoElement> _toDoItems = [];
  TextEditingController _controller = TextEditingController();
  TextEditingController _controller1 = TextEditingController();

  void _addToDoItem(String task) {
    if (task.isNotEmpty) {
      setState(() {
        _toDoItems.add(ToDoElement(task, DateTime.now()));
      });
    }
  }

  void _editToDoItem(String newText, int index) {
    setState(() {
      _toDoItems[index].task = newText;
    });
  }

  void _removeTodoItem(int index) {
    setState(() => _toDoItems.removeAt(index));
  }

  _editDialog(BuildContext context, int index) {
    return showDialog(
        context: context,
        builder: (context) {
          return Dialog(
            backgroundColor: Colors.transparent,
            child: Container(
              decoration: BoxDecoration(
                color: Colors.white,
                borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(20.0)),
              ),
              padding: EdgeInsets.all(20),
              height: 180,
              width: 100,
              child: Column(
                mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                children: [
                  Container(
                      height: 60,
                      child: TextField(
                        controller: _controller,
                        autofocus: true,
                        /*onSubmitted: (val) {
                      _addToDoItem(val);
                      _controller.clear();
                    },*/
                        style: TextStyle(
                          fontSize: 18,
                        ),
                        decoration: InputDecoration(
                          hintText: 'Add a task here...',
                          enabledBorder: OutlineInputBorder(
                            borderRadius:
                                BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(12.0)),
                            borderSide: BorderSide(color: Colors.red, width: 2),
                          ),
                          focusedBorder: OutlineInputBorder(
                            borderRadius:
                                BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(12.0)),
                            borderSide: BorderSide(color: Colors.red, width: 2),
                          ),
                        ),
                      )),
                  Container(
                    height: 65,
                    width: double.infinity,
                    margin: EdgeInsets.only(
                      top: 5,
                    ),
                    child: RaisedButton(
                      textColor: Colors.white,
                      color: Colors.red,
                      child: Text('EDIT', style: TextStyle(fontSize: 18)),
                      shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
                        borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(12)),
                      ),
                      onPressed: () {
                        _editToDoItem(_controller.text, index);
                        FocusScope.of(context).requestFocus(FocusNode());
                      },
                    ),
                  ),
                ],
              ),
            ),
          );
        });
  }

  Widget _buildToDoItem(String toDoText, int index) {
    return SizedBox(
      child: Container(
        height: 58,
        margin: EdgeInsets.only(
          left: 22.0,
          right: 22.0,
          bottom: 12,
        ),
        decoration: BoxDecoration(
          border: Border.all(width: 1.5, color: Colors.red),
          borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(18)),
        ),
        child: Row(
          crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
          children: [
            Expanded(
              child: ListTile(
                title: Text(
                  toDoText,
                  style: TextStyle(fontSize: 18),
                ),
                onTap: () => null,
              ),
            ),
            FlatButton(
              child: Text(
                'Edit',
                style: TextStyle(color: Colors.red, fontSize: 16.5),
              ),
              onPressed: () => _editDialog(context, index),
            ),
            FlatButton(
              child: Text(
                'Delete',
                style: TextStyle(color: Colors.red, fontSize: 16.5),
              ),
              onPressed: () => _removeTodoItem(index),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }

  int compareElement(ToDoElement a, ToDoElement b) =>
      a.timeOfCreation.isAfter(b.timeOfCreation) ? -1 : 1;

  Widget _buildToDoList() {
    _toDoItems.sort(compareElement);
    return Expanded(
      child: ListView.builder(
        itemCount: _toDoItems.length,
        itemBuilder: (context, index) {
          if (index < _toDoItems.length) {
            return _buildToDoItem(_toDoItems[index].task, index);
          }
        },
      ),
    );
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: PreferredSize(
          preferredSize: Size.fromHeight(50),
          child: AppBar(
            centerTitle: true,
            backgroundColor: Colors.red,
            title: Text(
              'To Do List',
              style: TextStyle(
                fontSize: 24,
                fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
              ),
            ),
          )),
      backgroundColor: Colors.white,
      body: GestureDetector(
        onTap: () {
          FocusScope.of(context).requestFocus(FocusNode());
        },
        child: Column(crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center, children: [
          Container(
            height: 60,
            margin: EdgeInsets.all(22),
            child: Row(
              crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
              children: [
                Expanded(
                  flex: 10,
                  child: Container(
                    height: double.infinity,
                    child: TextField(
                      controller: _controller1,
                      autofocus: true,
                      onSubmitted: (val) {
                        _addToDoItem(val);
                        _controller1.clear();
                      },
                      style: TextStyle(
                        fontSize: 18,
                      ),
                      decoration: InputDecoration(
                        hintText: 'Add a task here...',
                        enabledBorder: OutlineInputBorder(
                          borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(12.0)),
                          borderSide: BorderSide(color: Colors.red, width: 2),
                        ),
                        focusedBorder: OutlineInputBorder(
                          borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(12.0)),
                          borderSide: BorderSide(color: Colors.red, width: 2),
                        ),
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
                Expanded(
                  flex: 4,
                  child: Container(
                    height: double.infinity,
                    margin: EdgeInsets.only(left: 12),
                    child: RaisedButton(
                      textColor: Colors.white,
                      color: Colors.red,
                      child: Text('ADD', style: TextStyle(fontSize: 18)),
                      shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
                        borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(12)),
                      ),
                      onPressed: () {
                        _addToDoItem(_controller1.text);
                        _controller1.clear();
                        FocusScope.of(context).requestFocus(FocusNode());
                      },
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
              ],
            ),
          ),
          _buildToDoList()
        ]),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Hey!!! yout code worked, is there other  way to call _controller.text so that it doesnt change the addtoDoItem input?, because when editing it is changing the textfield value too when it should remain empty

Comment: you can use two TextEditingController, see updated full code

Comment: the reason is two TextField use the same TextEditController.

Comment: I just figured that out, to make the edit textfield of the selected element have the text of the selected element inside of it what should I do? I have been thinking in using the TextEditingController for it...

Comment: I try using `hintText: '${_toDoItem[index]}'` in the hintText of the dialog text fiel and I am getting "instance of ToDoElement" as an output, Do you have any ideas tof ix that?

Comment: please this is the last missing thing to finish this edit function

Comment: Need to reproduce, could you post reproduce code to a new question? thanks.